# Handling angularjs ui grid cell template ng-click function for var ctrl = this syntax in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I have the following columnDefs for my angularjs ui grid :

```
ctrl.temporaryRegGridOptions.columnDefs = [ {
            field: 'firstName',
            'displayName': 'First / Company Name',
            cellTemplate: '<span ng-click="ctrl.grid.appScope.gotoRequiredState()">{{row.entity.firstName}} </span> '
        }, {
            field: 'lastName',
            'displayName': 'Surname',
            width: '150'
        } ]
```

and I have

```
ctrl.gotoRequiredState = function() {
        alert("next State");
    }
```

All I need to do is, on ng-click of a cell I need to call a function.Similar to `ClicMe` at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope.  On the official website this feature is given with `$scope` but in my controller, I am  using `var ctrl = this`; syntax. May be that is the reason even if I have given `ng-click="grid.appScope.gotoRequiredState()">`, the `gotoRequiredState()` function is not getting called. So I have changed it to `ng-click="ctrl.grid.appScope.gotoRequiredState()">` but still no luck. Even after I click `firstName` cell, the  `gotoRequiredState()` function is not getting called.  Can any one help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The following has solved the problem :

```
ctrl.temporaryRegGridOptions.appScopeProvider = ctrl;
```

with

```
cellTemplate: '<span ng-click="grid.appScope.gotoRequiredState()">{{row.entity.firstName}} </span> '
```

works fine.

otherwise simply using :

```
 cellTemplate: '<span ng-click="grid.appScope.$parent.$ctrl.gotoRequiredState()">{{row.entity.firstName}} </span> '
```

works fine without assigning `ctrl` to `appScopeProvider`. By the way I am using Angularjs 1.5 + components architecture.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation that you have shared, I presume that appScope is the parent scope of the grid directive.

If thats the case, could you try

`ng-click="grid.appScope.ctrl.gotoRequiredState()"` ?